# How to get max lengthed item of item in list

Tags: python

Is there a way to do the following without a forloop?

```
list = ['https:', '', 'store.playstation.com', 'chihiro-api', 
        'viewfinder', 'BR', 'pt', '999', 'UV0004-NPVA17938_CN-0000000000029839'
        ]
get_max_lengthed_item(list)
==> 'UV0004-NPVA17938_CN-0000000000029839'
```

Comment: By max lengthened item, do you mean the longest item?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name as it is a built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `key` attribute of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function.

```
max(list, key=len)
```